# MvcMailer with Mvc5 is failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcmailer

Exception:

```
Attempt by method 'System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.String[], System.String[], System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.String[] ByRef)' to access method 'System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.get_DisplayModeProvider()' failed.
```

thrown by code:

```
return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.ViewName = "MyView";
                x.Subject = "[" + vm.FriendlyName + "] [" + DepResolver.DaemonAppSettingsHelper().EnvironmentName + "] [Status: " + vm.FriendlySuceeded + "]";
                x.To.Add(DepResolver.DaemonAppSettingsHelper().TaskEmailRecipient);
            });
```

How can I fix this issue>?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Nop, ended up using Spark email templates :/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered difficulties when updating a project to MVC5, which contained MVCMailer.  the following version install resolved it for me.

**Install-Package MvcMailer-vs2013 -Pre**

Further notes here: https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide